# How to create a loopback <model>.json file from unstructured data

Tags: loopbackjs

I can create a loopback model from an example json instance as shown here https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Creating+models+from+unstructured+data. But from there is there an API to create the .json file in common/models?

Comment: You can use loopback command line to create model's json.

Comment: Yes, but I want to do it programmatically.

Comment: You can lookup the code for the command line and re use it for your particular use then.

Comment: Great details @HarshilLodhi ! Hey Steve, yes you can use the tool to do the task.

Answer (score 0):

@BoLaMN from [Looback Gitter](https://gitter.im/strongloop/loopback) said this:

> try `app.registry.modelBuilder.introspect(json)`; that should give you a properties object. Then just add name, base to it and `fs.writeSync JSON.stringify(obj)`.

I haven't tried yet, but it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this:

```
  var User = db.buildModelFromInstance('User', user, {idInjection: true});

  var UserModel = (loopback.getModel(User));
  var UserModelJSON = {}  
  UserModelJSON.name = 'User';
  UserModelJSON.base = 'PersistedModel';
  UserModelJSON.properties = UserModel.definition.rawProperties;

  console.log(JSON.stringify(UserModelJSON));

  fs.writeFile('User.json', 'UserModelJSON', function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loopback `/server` directory at the root of your project, if you define the `datasources.json` file like so

```
{
  "db": {
    ...
  },
  "restResourceName": {
    "name": "restResourceName",
    "baseURL": "http://restResourceUrl/",
    "crud": true,
    "connector": "rest"
  }
}
```

And you define a boot script, like so

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const writeInstance = (server, modelName, instance) => {
  let Model = server.dataSources.restResourceName.buildModelFromInstance(modelName, instance)
  let modelJson = Model.definition.toJSON()
  delete modelJson.settings.base
  fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'models', modelName + '.json'),
    JSON.stringify(modelJson, null, 2), (/*...*/) => {
      /*...*/
    })
}

module.exports = function (server) {
  writeInstance(server, "Atom", {
    atomicWeight: 6
  })
}
```

You will generate a model file `Atom.json`

```
{
  "name": "Atom",
  "properties": {
    "atomicWeight": {
      "type": "Number"
    },
    "id": {
      "type": "Number",
      "id": 1,
      "generated": true,
      "updateOnly": true
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "strict": false,
    "forceId": "auto",
    "replaceOnPUT": true
  }
}
```

If you want to see the models in the loopback api explorer (swagger GUI), you must add the model to the `model-config.json` with a `public: true` property

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      ...
    ],
    "mixins": [
      ...
    ]
  },
  "Atom": {
    "public": true,
    "dataSource": "restResourceName"
  }
}
```

Comment: is this still relevant in Loopback 4?

Comment: @TekiusFanatikus I believe this was written with loopback 3